# Custom PhotoLibrary, and jpeg compression

Tags: ios, arrays, image, compression, photolibrary

I have to create a custom photolib like the default one, with animation etc. I had some doubts..

**1. Doubt**
Should I create 3 images (Thumbnail image, 320*480 image to display full image and original size image in case user share the image) (I am storing this all in app doc directory)
Or should I only store the original image and crop them wen required in 2 other images? In this case, if I use scroll view to display cropped images, how do I know what the user is seeing? And when do I crop next images to keep them ready to display? 
(Can anything like reusable cells be created here like in tableview? If yes, can you give me some idea?)

Also, I am fetching images from doc directory. In this case should I load all images in Array or load in batches?

**2. Problem Major:**
Also need to compress original image and keep it of same size (I used `uijpegrepresentation` with compression ratio but with some jpegs after compression. It increases sizes even double the size).

Comment: Hi @H Bastan  I've got similar question about jpeg file compression. My case is even worse. I got 10 times big file after compression comparing with the file saved by writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum. I've you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single image and for thumbnail you can Resize at run time else it increase size and performance issue. there is lots of open source library are there which do same what you needed. Please have a look below.

https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Comment: i can do runtime resizing of images ,but the numbers of images can be more say 200 , now in this case shd i resize all the images and load them all in array ...?

Comment: Yes it is the way, or you can try with some other library like three20 or above one..  may it will automatic handle resizing.